# How to increase the performance of sql query that contains a lot of joins and union

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have created a procedure in the following way,

```
create procedure proc_foo
as 
begin
declare @someVar int
set @someVar=0
if exists (select column1 from tbl1)
begin
set @someVar = 1
end
if exists (select column2 from tbl2)
begin
set @someVar = 1
end
....
...
....
if exists (select columnN from tblN)
begin
set @someVar = 1
end
if(@someVar =1)
begin
 select count(column1) from tbl1
 union
 select count(column2) from tbl2
 union
 ...
 ...
 ...
 select count(columnN) from tblN

end
end
```

The select statements contains a lot of joins and its taking a lot of time to execute.Can anyone explain to me a different approach that will be more faster.

Comment: One word: **indexing** .... search the web - there are **TONS** of good resources out there explaining how you can use proper indexing to improve query performance

Comment: Optimize the selects one at a time.  Post one.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest that you use the "WITH RECOMPILE" hint on your stored procedure.  This will recompile the SP and generate a new execution plan based on the how your variable ends up being set. Fresh execution plan every time.

Additionally, I would look into adding indexes on the columns that you are joining on and use INCLUDE columns if creating Non-Clustered Indexes for the columns you're outputting.